# Compile valgrind with an old MIPS gcc

Tags: gcc, mips, valgrind

Our embedded system use an old gcc - gcc version 3.4.4

When I compile the valgrind 3.9 for it, I found some errors. I handle them one by one, but for the last link error, I can't handle it:

```
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `find_chunk_for':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:287: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `find_active_chunks':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:333: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `lc_is_a_chunk_ptr':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:523: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `lc_push':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:563: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `pp_heuristic':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:593: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `aligned_ptr_above_page0_is_vtable_addr':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:612: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
memcheck_mips32_linux-mc_leakcheck.o: In function `heuristic_reachedness':
/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c:687: relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'
```

I tried to add the -G4 option to recompile, but failed:

```
./configure --host=mips-linux --prefix=/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0/valgrind_install CFLAGS="-G4"
```

Configure will fail and will show:

```
****configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used****
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for mips-linux-strip... mips-linux-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for mips-linux-gcc... mips-linux-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/storage/source/valgrind-3.9.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I even tried to modify the generate Makefile and add -G4 option to C_FLAGS, but it doesn't work. I still cannot compile file with the -G4 option.

1. I don't know if -G4 option can resolve this link error.  If yes, what should I do?
2. Is there any other way to make valgrind work with my tool chain?

I can't change this tool chain to a newer version because it is bound with the whole system.

Comment: Try -mxgot compiler option.

Comment: It doesn't work. Link error still shows:relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_HI16 against `_gp_disp'

Comment: `See 'config.log' for more details`: what does config.log say?

Comment: Similar problem. Any known solutions?